# Find distance to nearest cell in each cardinal direction with value "#"?

Tags: excel, artificial-intelligence, excel-formula

To phrase it differently, how many cells must you go down, up, left, and right before you find a cell with value "#"?

The desired end result is for the cell to display how directions you can go at least 'x' cells before you find a cell that has the value "#".

I am a bit of a newb, and am sure this question is not exactly the normal sort, but I can't seem to find any information anywhere that would point me to a solution of any kind.

battleship board distribution of possible placements for four tile long ship: turn 0

[image: turn-0]

battleship board distribution of possible placements for four tile long ship: turn 1

[image: turn-1]

Comment: I don't understand how you calculate your numbers. For example, starting from top left, why is the 3rd row 3rd column number 2 ? It is 3 squares from left or top and it can go in all directions.

Comment: The "ship" is four tiles long as stated above the picture. Assuming that "front" of the ship occupies the tile you mention, there is not room for the rest of the ship in two of the four directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled a little bit before going to work.

Ended up with a partial formula

```
=MIN(ROW(B2)-ROW(Upper_edge),ROW(Lower_edge)-ROW(B2),COLUMN(B2)-COLUMN(Left_edge),COLUMN(Right_edge)-COLUMN(B2),MATCH("#",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B2),COLUMN(B2)+1) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW(B2),COLUMN(Right_edge)))))
```

The formula needs workout for MATCH to left, up and down, similar to the MATCH in the formula

The Excel file is available in 
http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Battleship_distance.xls

Comment: Thank you, I was able to take it from there.